# Rails: cannot change email after signed up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have a User model and some common columns, such as `name`, `email`, `password`, etc.

and here is the thing:
i donot want a user changing his email address after signed up, what should i do?

just don't include the email field in the update form?
and i think the `attr_accessible` is not for this use either.

what do you suggest? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

- `attr_readonly`

The documentation says the following

> Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but update operations will ignore these fields.

So, a new record can be created with an `email` but you can never change it (without a hack) after the record has been created.